# why does Webresource.axd attempt to 'download' when I reference it in this URL?

Tags: asp.net, webresource.axd, xss

I have someone doing a penetration test on a site and they are trying to exploit WebResource.axd
I'm confused because whenever I try his URL I either get it trying to download to a text file in IE or displaying as text on FF

```
https://www.abc.com/admin/WebResource.axd?d=RwbBVERJr4odqFAEhrTxZocB3t466Wz_wzC0J-SrAE-W4xu-AzmjqZkrwGODx5_afw_duUtD5UrVO_hDOpznd5ZG60E1&t=634219309938290489&%3E%27%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%2816146%29%3C%2Fscript%3E=123
```

He says that it is giving him an alert with 16146 in it, I can't fix it because I can't even duplicate it.

I have customErrors defined within web.config, everything is going to the same concise error page.  I kind of get how you COULD exploit this file but I just want to know what I managed to do that causes it to come across text.

HELP?!?

Comment: what is the text that's being displayed in FF ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what's being served up. It's likely to be the content-type header that's causing IE to try and download the page.